# "printf" can't work well on a thread?

Tags: c

code as below：

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void* fetch();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &fetch, NULL);
}


void* fetch()
{
    printf("start...\n");
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        printf("fetch...\n");
    }
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

why this code does not work well through I run it more times. HELP!  when i do 
    $gcc thread_test.c
    $./a.out
it print out nothing!
when i run it more time:

Ye! print out:
start...
fetch...

WHY?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "does not work well"? Do you get the wrong output? No output? Too much?

Comment: @FredrikPihl: Ironically, a wok is designed to allow multithreaded cooking, by providing both hotter and colder areas for cooking and storing, respectively. And big international meetings usually provide a global interpreter wok.

Comment: yes, it can print something,such as : "start... fetch..", but just one "fetch..."

Comment: `void*fetch()` is not the right prototype for a function that is to be launched through `pthread_create`. It is missing the argument. Running a function with the wrong signature is *undefined behavior*, your stack can be smashed or ugly things like that. Don't do it, your compiler should have warned you.

Comment: the prototype of pthread_create is pthread_create(pthread_t *tid, const pthread_attr_t *tattr, void*(*start_routine)(void *), void *arg); the only different is void*fetch() is not void*fetch(void *var) but i did't get any warning or error!!

Comment: Where is Join?, you need to use pthread_join()

Answer (score 9):

Your program will exit when your main thread exits.  There are no guarantees how threads will be scheduled; `fetch` may sometimes run before `main` exits, other times `main` will exit first.

If you want to wait for the child thread, you need to add a call to join its thread.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &fetch, NULL);
    return pthread_join(tid, NULL);
}
```

The call to [pthread_join](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_join) blocks until the thread with id `tid` exits so guarantees that all of your `printf` calls will be executed.

Comment: quick question: if main thread finishes, `*fetch()` will exit independently of what it is doing ?

Comment: Yes, when your main thread completes your program completes.  Its resources will be automatically reclaimed, including any running threads.

Answer (score 1):

use `pthread_join` to wait for the second thread..